# Do I Need To Change the Tire If the Sidewall Is Damaged Like This? Is this cosmetic or safety hazard?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage, tesla

The front right tire of my car got a sidewall cut as shown in the picture.

Should I replace the tire? I'm wondering if this is cosmetic or safety hazard. This is Tesla model 3 with about 8000 miles on it.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The damage doesn't seem too deep however I always tell people to replace their tire if there is Sidewall damage. Sidewall damages are most dangerous one. The tires weakest spot is Sidewall. If you drive with this tire at high speed it can start to wobble and pop out of nowhere. Since it won't be a tiny hole that will lose air gradually, but a serious pop you might lose control and crash. Just change the tire. Would you really risk lives just to save few bucks?